# Edge Detection cv2 on bubbles

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

I have problems to do a proper edge detection on the following picture. My goal is to get an edge detecion  arround every individual bubble. I used Canny edge detection from cv2, the bubbles that are to close together are merged. Do you have any idea how i can detect any individual bubble?

Thanks 
best regards

[Hight Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRq8u.png)
[Edge Detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trkzX.png)

[file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au0q1QQdkvYZgbp43UaL4crVHNWw1g?e=sFp6sA)

Comment: Your bubbles are "ugly". Can you show us the ground truth, i.e. which bubbles should be reported ?

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes you are right the bubbles are ugly. i need to find every round object in the hight profile.

Comment: Sorry, this comment doesn't bring any information.